# How do I make a picture seem like a radiobutton?

Tags: android

I am attempting to use my own buttons to make an overlay at the bottom of the screen. When a button is pressed it should light up (kind of how a radio button turns green when selected) and it should take you to a new activity while keeping the overlay intact.

There are five buttons that should be put on a black bar and when selected it should turn blue.

If someone could send me in the right direction I would be very grateful. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [StateListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html)s for your buttons.